# wordpress shortcode for tab

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

i added this by custom post type. but i want to create this by shortcode method with the conditional statement. how to do this ? please anyone ans this ?

```
            <?php
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type'=> 'tab-items');
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            ?>
            <!--nab section date content area-->
            <div class="date_section_area">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <div class="date_section_list">
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                            <li><a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php endforeach; 
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="date_section_content">
                    <?php foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div class="single_date_section_content tab-pane fade" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('tab-image'); ?>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; 
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `shortcode method with the conditional statement` ?

Comment: i have used this with custom post type. now i want to use this with shortcode. and conditional means i want to use this with few styles. if user set the category or name or anything , then my another style will show. how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question,

i have an idea that you can do like this:-

```
add_shortcode('my_post_shorcode', 'my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function($attr, $content)
{
    extract(
        shortcode_atts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => '4',
            'post_type' => 'tab-items',
            'style' => 'default'
        ), $atts)
    );

    if($style == 'style-1')
    {
        //Add Your Style-1
    } else if($style == 'style-2') {
        //Add Your Style-2
    } else {
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'post_type'=> $post_type);
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        $tab_title = "";
        $tab_content = "";
        foreach ($myposts as $post)
        {
            setup_postdata($post);

            $tab_title .= '<li><a href="#tab-post-'.the_ID().'" data-toggle="tab">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
            $tab_content .= '<div class="single_date_section_content tab-pane fade" id="tab-post-'.the_ID().'>
            ' . the_post_thumbnail('tab-image') . the_content() . '
            </div>';

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        ?>
        <!--nab section date content area-->
        <div class="date_section_area">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <div class="date_section_list">
                <ul>
                    <?php echo $tab_title;?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="date_section_content">
                <?php echo $tab_content;?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
    } 
}
```

And shortcode will be like this:-

```
[my_post_shorcode posts_per_page="4" post_type="tab-items" style="default"]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: using tab (e.g. bootstrap tab), there would be few title and content in each group. so how to add this in my post ?

Comment: I am not getting what are you saying. please explain more.

Comment: actually , in my theme, i want to use a tab like this (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) that why, i have created this for wordpress my site with custom post type with my code which i asked here. it works fine. but if i use with custom post type then i can only use this is a specific template. i want to use this tab anywhere in my site. thats why i need to create this with shortcode. there is my problem to use this with shortcode. and lastly i have created this tab in my html site with various styles only changing the div classes.

Comment: so i want to use this with shortcode and also want to use other styles tab so that the user/me can use the other style, changing only a single word(e.g category or name or like something)

Comment: But you can use this shortcode anywhere you want in your site...
And one more thing, if you want to add more options in shortcode than just add like i added `style, posts_per_page, & post_type`. and user as i used in function.